# How do I properly pass a new key to a JSON dictionary?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to add a new key to a JSON file, but I'm not having much success with it. The JSON file is one dictionary with a whole bunch of dictionaries nested in there. I'm trying to pass a new key and value at the same time to all those nested dictionaries like this:

```
with open("booksset1.json") as books:
 bookData = json.load(books)

with open("booksset1.json", "w") as books:


 init = 0
 for book in bookData["books"]:
  bookData["books"][init]["ISBN"] = init
  init += 1

  json.dump(bookData, books, indent=4)
```

But when I execute this code, this error shows up.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I'm not quite sure what is going wrong here. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: Maybe when your first attempt failed, you accidently deleted (emptied) your input file.

Comment: Huh. That's exactly what happened, strangely enough.

Comment: It is not that strange. The `bookData` processing does not have to happen in the context of the opened output file (especially if that is the input file as well). If anything goes wrong there (Exception), the closing file handle will flush and the file will be empty.  Just put only the file writing code within the `with`-block. Here, only the `json.dump(...)` line.